# Arduino - what does the code mean?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, bit-shift, boolean-logic

I am just a student working with Arduino and am wondering what the below code means. I have referenced it and everything. Thank you

```
void RGB(unsigned long valor) {
   r = valor >> 16; 
   g = (valor >> 8) & 0xFF; 
   b = valor & 0xFF; 
}
```

Comment: It sets the variable `b` which is presumably the blue component of an image pixel, to the bottom 8 bits of `valor`. It extacts the red and green components from the adjacent bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **>>** - The symbol of right shift operator is **>>**. For its operation, it requires two operands. It shifts each bit in its left operand to the right. The number following the operator decides the number of places the bits are shifted (i.e. the right operand). Thus by doing `ch >> 3` all the bits will be shifted to the right by three places and so on. 
  For example:

  ```
  i = 14; // Bit pattern 00001110
  j = i >> 1; // here we have the bit pattern shifted by 1 thus we get 00000111 = 7 which is 14/2
  ```
- **&** - The bitwise AND operator is a single ampersand: **&**. It is just a representation of AND which does its work on the bits of the operands rather than the truth value of the operands. Bitwise binary AND does the logical AND (as shown in the table above) of the bits in each position of a number in its binary form. Here is char of inputs and output combinations:

  ```
  +------+-------+---------------+
  |bit a | bit b |a & b (a AND b)|
  +------+-------+---------------+
  |  0   |   0   |       0       |
  |  0   |   1   |       0       |
  |  1   |   0   |       0       |
  |  1   |   1   |       1       |
  +------+-------+---------------+
  ```

  For example:

  ```
    11001000  
  & 10111000 
    -------- 
  = 10001000
  ```

Comment: Ok thanks, this will help in my commenting